# Filebeat stops sending data to Logstash and hence Elasticsearch after a few hundred thousand documents, works again on restarting Filebeat container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to Elastic stack and I am using Filebeat AWS module's vpcflow to fetch data from S3 through SQS. It works fine for a few hundred thousand documents, but after that I don't see any new document in Elasticsearch index. On restarting the Filbeat container, data starts moving again and stops again after 200000 - 300000 documents.

My flow is: S3 --> SQS --> Filebeat --> Logstash --> Elasticsearch Index

Things look fine to me, Filebeat and Logstash docker logs has no errors or warnings and look normal.

Filebeat docker logs look like:

```
|2021-07-29T12:34:34.451Z|INFO|[monitoring]|log/log.go:144|Non-zero metrics in the last 30s|{monitoring: {metrics: {beat:{cgroup:{cpuacct:{total:{ns:18501726}}},cpu:{system:{ticks:8920},total:{ticks:73170,time:{ms:21},value:73170},user:{ticks:64250,time:{ms:21}}},handles:{limit:{hard:1048576,soft:1048576},open:10},info:{ephemeral_id:20bbba13-a550-4736-9100-5d5e9bc8d253,uptime:{ms:18210111}},memstats:{gc_next:22657664,memory_alloc:11578696,memory_total:8351052936,rss:79257600},runtime:{goroutines:24}},filebeat:{harvester:{open_files:0,running:0}},libbeat:{config:{module:{running:1},scans:3},output:{events:{active:0}},pipeline:{clients:6,events:{active:2069}}},registrar:{states:{current:0}},system:{load:{1:0.08,15:0.02,5:0.06,norm:{1:0.04,15:0.01,5:0.03}}}}}}|
|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|2021-07-29T12:35:04.450Z|INFO|[monitoring]|log/log.go:144|Non-zero metrics in the last 30s|{monitoring: {metrics: {beat:{cgroup:{cpuacct:{total:{ns:9612964}}},cpu:{system:{ticks:8930,time:{ms:5}},total:{ticks:73180,time:{ms:8},value:73180},user:{ticks:64250,time:{ms:3}}},handles:{limit:{hard:1048576,soft:1048576},open:10},info:{ephemeral_id:20bbba13-a550-4736-9100-5d5e9bc8d253,uptime:{ms:18240110}},memstats:{gc_next:22657664,memory_alloc:12050688,memory_total:8351524928,rss:79257600},runtime:{goroutines:24}},filebeat:{harvester:{open_files:0,running:0}},libbeat:{config:{module:{running:1},scans:3},output:{events:{active:0}},pipeline:{clients:6,events:{active:2069}}},registrar:{states:{current:0}},system:{load:{1:0.05,15:0.01,5:0.05,norm:{1:0.025,15:0.005,5:0.025}}}}}}|
```

Logstash docker logs look like:

```
[2021-07-29T07:29:45,822][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.10+9 on 11.0.10+9 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2021-07-29T07:29:47,985][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-07-29T07:29:50,446][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 52 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values 
[2021-07-29T07:29:50,913][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.inputs.beats] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2021-07-29T07:29:52,470][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>1000, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>1000, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1b9b01f9 run>"}
[2021-07-29T07:29:54,337][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.86}
[2021-07-29T07:29:54,399][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ][main] Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:7044"}
[2021-07-29T07:29:54,434][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2021-07-29T07:29:54,552][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2021-07-29T07:29:54,662][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main][1dfc980bac0254f76e50245873af080551f4b8ff5bc18e9eef4f724a86e99061] Starting server on port: 7044
```

Can anyone help me to understand the issue here or if I am missing anything in my pipeline? Do I need to configure some configurations in logstash.yml (workers, batch_size, etc) or anything on Filebeat side?

Please redirect me to relevant post if this scenario already answered and I may have missed during my search before this post.

Note: I am using Elastic stack version 7.12.1 for all Filebeat, Logstash and Elasticsearch and docker containers for all of them.